# Application Issue, WHOIS database

Tags: whois

There is an application to search WHOIS database directly:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897435

When I opened it at first time, I accepted the agreement, but closed it immediately after that. Now, each time I try to open this app, it opens and closes immediately. Same happens on another laptop.

What is the problem?

Comment: It is not on topic - see the [help/on-topic] - unless you actually wrote that program. (If so, you should post the problematic code.)

Comment: I know mate, I will delete it immediately after I'll get the answer..

Comment: I think it is quite common thing, as well as it is a very small app from microsoft to give it a try

Comment: .. *After* you get an answer? That is not how off-topic questions usually are handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a command line tool. You should use the command prompt (dos prompt) to use it. Open the command prompt by pressing the Windows Key + R, type CMD and press enter.
Then navigate to the folder where you extractd the zip file and type:
whois -v stackoverflow.com
And you get the whois information

Comment: Luc, Thanks, but it doesn't work... It says "The system cannot find the path specified" Any ideas?

Comment: This might 2 thing: 1: You didn't extract the zipfile you downloaded 2: You are not in the correct folder